# How can I burn a 706MB image onto a 703MB CD?

Tags: iso, burning

The Ubuntu image ubuntu-12.04.3-alternate-i386.iso is 706MB large.

I thought that little 3MB extra at the end is just the MB/MiB error - so the image should fit on the disk. But I was wrong.

My disk has 703MB. Is there a trick to burn the image regardless?

Comment: So what do you want? That they slice something they consider important in a distribution and make Ubuntu 12.04 angryme edition so you can use your 703MB disk??? This is a Q/A site, not a complain box!

Comment: I think what you are trying to figure out is, how to overburn a disc. Post a fresh question and don't complain there.

Comment: @realmoonstruck Rather than posting a separate question to ask about the same thing, it would be better for angryme to edit this question. Multiple questions by the same author about exactly the same thing are discouraged. However, this question really as answerable as is--it is already asking *how to burn the image*, after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.  It worked for me about 75% of the time.  I used [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), and set the default Overburning Method to Truncate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Options are to

1. burn it on a DVD; or
2. use the directions to create a bootable USB stick.

What is on the ISO is what they felt was the **minimum needed** for distributing an installer.

As Salem notes, this is a Q&A site, not a complaint department for Canonical. We all have to deal with the same issue. Options are provided to circumvent the CD size limitation. I have used both methods and they work.